# html nav in body with same color, css rgba color doesn't behave consistently

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a navbar and a body with the same color, using RGBA. Unfortunately, when I use the exact same color on the nav and the body, using css variables to make sure it's right, I get a different result in the two elementss.

Minimal example down below.  I'd like the background to foo to be the same as the background to bar, and don't understand why it isn't.

There's additional additional complexity that makes it suboptimal for me to take the obvious solution, namely to let the nav element just inherit from the body.  See below the snippet for explanation.

```css
:root {
    --main-bg-color: rgba(172, 196, 165, 0.75);
}

body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar-default">foo</nav>
        bar
    </body>
</html>
```

Additional relevant information: I'm overriding some Bootstrap classes with the nav, and I would prefer not to just build and host my own local version of bootstrap to get this right.  The upshot is that I can't just drop the background-color on the nav and let it inherit from the body. If I drop my own css it gets the color from miserable bootstrap defaults and ends up white.  I guess I can go and get a local bootstrap if I have to, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is make `.navbar-default` transparent.

```css
:root {
    --main-bg-color: rgba(172, 196, 165, 0.75);
}

body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<nav class="navbar-default">foo</nav>
bar
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ooooh, I didn't know that transparent was an option for background colors.  Thanks, that does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

While one element is over the other, the transparency of 0.75 makes the difference.

The transparency is defined by the alpha value of RGB**A** and is the last value:

rgba(172, 196, 165, **0.75**)

More about rgba:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space
- https://css-tricks.com/the-power-of-rgba/

Think of making 2 layers in a photo editor filled with a color and then 75% transparency value, and then overlap them.

Also think what color may be behind the body element, that can differ from browser to browser, so a full color may be more consistent here.

Comment: so the transparency is being added somehow?  hmm... do you know a formula to convert two overlaid transparencies to get an effective transparency or something like that?

Comment: ah ok, i added an explanation where the alpha comes from

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the transparency setting at 75% (0.75) looks to be the issue as essentially 25% of the background behind your body will bleed through.  If this is not the case you may want to check that:

1) you don't have any "style" attributes in your HTML that would be overwriting your CSS

or

2) you don't have any CSS below this that is inherited by the nav or body.

Answer (score 0):

the `0.75` at the last said color is the transparency, I tried removing it on jsfiddle and now it works... same color

```
:root {
    --main-bg-color: rgba(172, 196, 165);
}
```

Here it is, I removed the `0.75` as it is the transparency of the color.

Comment: i would then recommend rgb(172, 196, 165) or #ACC4A5